# Blazor execute C# and JS function in one button onclick event

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor

I  have a button, which executes a JS function:

```
<button class="btn-orange btn" onclick="expand(this.closest('.profile'))">JavaScript</button>
```

And a button, which executes C# and switches icons depending on a bool:

```
<button class="btn-orange btn"
   @onclick="@(() =>
   {
      if (tempBool)
      {
         tempBool = !tempBool;
      }
      else
      {
         tempBool = true;
      }
   })">
   <i class="fa @(tempBool ? "fa-compress" : "fa-expand")" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

How can I combine them?

I tried it with the `OnClientClick` Event, with                                  `JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("expand(this.closest(.profile))");`, or by putting both in the onclick event.

How can I execute a JavaScript function and C# in a button onclick event?

My JavaScript code I try to execute

EventPageExpandable.js:

```
function expand(card) {
    card.classList.toggle('profile--expanded');

    // If card is not expanded after toggle, add 'unexpanded' class
    if (!card.classList.contains('profile--expanded')) card.classList.toggle('profile--unexpanded');

    // Else if card is expanded after toggle and still contains 'unexpanded' class, remove 'unexpanded'
    else if (card.classList.contains('profile--expanded') && card.classList.contains('profile--unexpanded')) card.classList.toggle('profile--unexpanded');
}
```

How I tried to use JsRuntime:

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("EventPageExpandable.expand", "this.closest('.profile')");
```

Or like this? But both doesn't work.

````
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("expand", "this.closest('.profile')");```
````

Comment: Do you want to excute two functions or you want to fire two buttons?

Comment: I want to execute the JS function and the C# code with one button. That when I press it, it executes both

Comment: Why do you want to fire the JS? It is just changing classes on an element - you can do that in your C# code

Comment: That's a really good question. I've tried it out, but sadly the Element is a custom one from Blazorstrap and does not support complex content (mixed C# and markup) :/

Comment: Okay, swapped it out with the card of bootstrap. works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject the JSRuntime:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
```

Bind the onclick event of the button:

```
<button @onclick=ButtonClicked>Test</button>
```

and execute the JavaScript function:

```
private async Task ButtonClicked()
{
    Console.WriteLine("From C#");
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "From js");
}
```

When invoking JS-functions, pass the function name as first argument followed by all parameters

Comment: I've tried it with the JsRuntime but I dont know how to correctly pass on parameters, because when I put this.closest('.profile') into quotation marks, it just parses it as string and does not gets the closest parent with a "parent" class. 
Removing the quotation marks, leaves errors because "this" does not contain ".closest"

Comment: So the problem is that you can't pass JS parameters?
I'm not sure if that can be done, however you could do a little workaround by defining a parameterless JS function that uses `this.closest('.profile')`

Comment: When I execute the JS function like this: onclick="expand(this.closest('.profile'))", it transfers the parameter (div.card.profile), when I execute the function with JsRuntime, it parses the parameter just as a string: 'this.closest('.profile')'. 

I don't think that I can use this as a parameterless function, because I need to target a specific element, because there are multiple of.

Comment: What I meant as a temporary solution is:
`function expand2() {
    expand(this.closest('.profile'));
}`
And invoke this